# CSS + jQuery - Unable to perform .toggle() and repeated jQueryTemplate Item [I must warn you this is a bit overwhelming]

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

Okay here we go:

## Stream.html (Template file)

```
<div class="streamItem clearfix">
    <input type="button" />

    <div class="clientStrip">
        <img src="" alt="${Sender}" />
    </div>
    <div class="clientView">
        <a href="#" class="clientName">${Sender}</a>
        <p>${Value}</p> 
        <p>${DateTime}</p>  

        <div class="itemGadgets">
            <ul>
                <li class="toggleInput">Value</li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="inputContainer">
            <input type="text" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer" />
```

## Default.aspx (jQuery)

```
$('.toggleInput').live('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().parent()
        .find('.inputContainer').toggle();

    $(this).parent().parent().find('.inputContainer')
        .find('input[type=text]').focus();
});
```

## Update: The above has been changed to:

```
        $('.toggleInput').live('click', function () {
            $(this).closest(".clientView").find(".inputContainer").toggle()
            $(this).closest(".clientView").find(".inputContainer")
            .find('input[type=text]').focus();
        });
```

**Issues with jQuery:**

1. I have comments that belong to each `.streamItem`. My previous solution was to use `ListView` control as follows:

   ```
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Panel ID="StreamItem" CssClass="StreamItem" runat="server">
       ...
       <!--  Insert another nested ListView control here to load the comments for the parent stream. -->
   ```

   So as you can see, this is not a solution since I started using jQuery Templates and I am fetching the data using the following jQuery `$.ajax` method:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'Services.asmx/GetStream',
       data: "{}",
       contentType: 'application/json',
       success: function (Stream) {
           $.get('Templates/Stream.html', function (template) {
               $.tmpl(template, Stream.d).appendTo("#Stream");
           });
       }
   });
   ```

   **How can I resolve this without using the old `ListView` solution but by using jQuery Templates to load the comments whenever I am getting data for a specific stream?** I am using a simple `WebMethod` to return my data as follows:

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public List<Stream> GetStream()
   {
       List<Stream> Streams = Stream.GetRange(X, X, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
       return Streams;
   }
   ```
2. I am looking for a way to handle the `.toggleInput` click event. I need check if `.Comments` (a main container for the (to be comments container `<div>`)) has children (or more than one `.commentItem`). If so, then I need to show that `.inputContainer` and hide all the other `.inputContainer divs` with .Comments `size() == 0` if they're visible.

Please see the image below:

[image]

## Update: CSS Issue below is resolved. (I had a conflict)

```
#globalContainer div 
{
    float               : right;
    position            : relative;
    display             : inline-block; /* <-- Thank you Firebug. */
}
```

## Default.aspx (Partial CSS)

```
div.streamItem div.clientView
{
    float               : left;
    width               : 542px;
}
div.streamItem div.clientView p
{
    margin              : 5px 0 0 0;
    font-size           : 10pt; 
}
div.streamItem div.clientView
div.inputContainer 
{
    display             : none; /* Doesn't hide .inputContainer */
    padding             : 2px;
    background-color    : #f1f1f1;
}
```

**Issues with CSS:**

On page load, `display: none;` has no effect.

That's it! If you're reading this I'd like to thank you for your time and thoughts! :)

Comment: I'm not sure your jQuery live event is right. When I tested it in a jsfiddle, it returned `<div class="itemGadgets">`, instead of `<div class="clientView">`. What happens if you change `.parent().parent()` (which is smelly code, to be honest) to `.closest(".clientView")`? Also, it's a little hard to figure out what exactly you're asking. Could you summarize your problems and questions at the beginning of the question?

Comment: Hi jwiscarson, I am trying to toggle `inputContainer` I've tried this now as per your suggestion `            $('.toggleInput').live('click', function () {
                $(this).closest('.inputContainer').toggle();` nothing happens there.

Comment: It wouldn't -- `.closest()` traverses **up** the DOM tree. .inputContainer is not a parent of .toggleInput, so `.closest()` isn't going to return anything for you. You would need `$(this).closest(".clientView").find(".inputContainer").toggle()`, but again -- that's ugly looking jQuery and should probably be refactored.

Comment: I agree, it's ugly jQuery again but this does at least select the control I'm trying to toggle.

Comment: No, the problem is that it does **not** select the control. The parent of the `<li>` is its `<ul>`, and the parent of that is the `<div>` around the `<ul>`.  From there, ".find()" **only** looks inside the `<div>`, so it won't see that ".inputContainer" since it's a sibling.

Comment: It should be `$(this).closest('.cientView').find('.inputContainer')`

Comment: But .toggle() now works on the target control `.inputContainer`.

Comment: as a warning, `.live()` has been removed from jQuery 1.7, so if/when you upgrade you'll have some issues.  i would suggest looking into `.delegate()` instead.

Comment: Live is removed matters then tmpl library is also not supported anymore... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yuo are trying to access elements in wrong place

in **js**:

```
 $('.toggleInput').live('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent()
....
```

is  it has no .inputContainer child element - there is nothing to toggle

(.closest wouldn't work also, because .inputContainer is not a parent of the .toggleInput, but its parents sibling )

---

jQuery selector would be $(this).closest('.itemGadgets').next();

---

for 2.

inside your click handler

```
var $currentInputContainer =  $(this).closest(".clientView").find(".inputContainer");
....
$('.inputContainer').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);

   $this.toggle( $('.commentItem', $this).length > 0 );

});

//but it is better always to show the inputContainer which link was clicked
$('.inputContainer').not($currentInputContainer).each(function(){./*toggle empty|not empty containers */..});
$currentInputContainer.show();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. `<div class='inputContainer' />` is inside `.clientView` as shown in the HTML Template above. Also, .closest() as jwiscarson and Pointy suggested seems to target the control. I've updated the jQuery code in my  post please take a look. Thanks ;)

Comment: `.inputContainer` is not a sibling of `.toggleInput`. `.itemGadgets` is.

Comment: it was a typo   .., see selector

Comment: This is still misleading. What you have there now states that `.inputContainer` is a sibling of the `<ul>` tag. Also, if you could add code tags to your answer, that would improve it. I dislike using `.next()` because it's ambiguous in code and makes code very quick to fail at the slightest DOM change, but your actual selector is correct (and yes, I know I'm pedantic :) ).

Comment: @jwiscarson: ok :), you can use closest('.itemGadgets').siblings('inputContainer'); it's more stable

Comment: I am working on this again today, I still did not implement your solution. But i'll let you know as soon as I do. Thank you.